# Angular fails to instantiate app in production - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

My JS is failing in production. I've tried a few different approaches to no success. My JS is:

```
angular
  .module('MyApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'templates',
    'ui.bootstrap.tpls',
    'ui.bootstrap',
  ])
  .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'home.html',
      controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    })
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }])
```

And My controllers are instantiated using the following syntax

```
angular.module('MyApp')

.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.user;
}])
```

Applicaiton.js

```
//= require angular
//= require angular-route
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require thirdparty/jquery-2.1.1.min.js
//= require myapp/app.js
//= require myapp/controllers/myapp.js
//= require thirdparty/ui-bootstrap-tpls.0.11.0.js
//= require_tree ../templates
```

and finally my application.html

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

However I keep getting the following error `[$injector:nomod] Module 'MyApp' is not available!`. I know it's something simple but this is driving me crazy. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check that your `<script>` tags for Angular-related files are declared with the correct order (i.e. the file that instantiates the 'MyApp' app is first)